# How to add back the elements after removing every element by document.getElementById in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I had this case where I remove the elements by using document.getElementById to target whom to be used, then remove it by doing element.remove(). I only wanted to add it back for me to use the classList.toggle again

p.s. 'test' and '.settings-menu' are on the same div, I only used id and class and only wanted to know how to return the elements back after removing, I also specifically wanted to use el.remove() rather than classList.remove() for a specific purpose.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');
let settingsmenu = document.querySelector (".settings-menu");
function removeClass(){
  el.remove();
}

function addclass(){
   settingsmenu.classList.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to remove it? If you only want to _hide_ it, then you should probably use `display: none` instead...

Comment: yes, I had to force it to remove the element and add it back later on, because i had this experience where i use classlist.remove but it didn't totally hide and just shows off again after clicking the hamburger/collapse button in bootstrap which is not supposed to happen, so i had to remove it totally which works and add it back later (which i don't know how to put back the elements again for classList.toggle to work again) @JongwooLee

Comment: You used `classList.toggle()` but you didn't use any parameters. You should specify the class name you want to toggle. Can you explain what you expect it to behave like?

Comment: the classList.toggle uses the settings-menu to be toggled on and off, should i include it here in the code? But i only wanted to know how to put the elements back on "el" , sorry if I misunderstand something @JongwooLee

Comment: I think you're thinking wrong about that, `classList.remove` does _not_ hide that element, it only removes a class from the element. You should use CSS to hide the element. Removing it from the DOM is a bad approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example offers 4 different solutions:

- When the page `load`s, the load event is triggered, adding the child `<div>` element to the page.
- Clicking the "Toggle Element" button will show/hide the child `<div>` element.
- Clicking the "Toggle Class" button will add/remove the `customStyle` class style to the child `<div>` element.
- Clicking the "Remove Element" button removes the child `<div>` element from the page.
- Clicking the "Add Element" button will add the child `<div>` element to the page.

```js
var toggleElementButton = document.getElementById('toggleElement');
var toggleClassButton = document.getElementById('toggleClass');
var removeClassButton = document.getElementById('removeClass');
var parentContainer = document.getElementById('parent');

/* HTML element to add dynamically. */
var element = `<div id="test" class="customStyle" style="display: block;">TEST</div>`;

/* The dynamic element is added to the page when the page loads. */
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  parentContainer.innerHTML += element;
});

/* Clicking the "Toggle Element" button will show/hide the item. */
toggleElementButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  var currentElement = document.getElementById('test');
  
  if(document.getElementById('test').style.display == "none")
    currentElement.style.display = "block";
  else
    currentElement.style.display = "none";
});

/* Clicking the "Toggle Class" button adds/removes the class style. */
toggleClassButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementById('test').classList.toggle("customStyle");
});

/* Clicking the "Remove Element" button removes the item.       */
/* When the "Add Element" button is clicked, the item is added. */
removeClassButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(removeClassButton.innerHTML == "Remove Element")
  {
    document.getElementById('test').remove();
    removeClassButton.innerHTML = "Add Element";
    toggleElementButton.disabled = true;
    toggleClassButton.disabled = true;
  }
  else if(removeClassButton.innerHTML == "Add Element")
  {
    parentContainer.innerHTML += element;
    removeClassButton.innerHTML = "Remove Element";
    toggleElementButton.disabled = false;
    toggleClassButton.disabled = false;
  }   
});
```

```css
.container{
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.customStyle{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<button id="toggleElement">Toggle Element</button>
<button id="toggleClass">Toggle Class</button>
<button id="removeClass">Remove Element</button>

<div id="parent" class="settings-menu container">
  <!-- The item is dynamically added and removed here. -->
</div>
```

Comment: i'll test it on my side and will leave a comment about its output, thanks for this ^_^

Comment: thank you very much for your help ^_^, the block and none works as to what i wanted to happen

Answer (score 0):

An easier way is to use `hidden`:

```js
var el = document.getElementById('test');
let settingsmenu = document.querySelector(".settings-menu");

function hideElem() {
  el.hidden = true
}

function showElem() {
  el.hidden = false
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hideElem()">Hide TEST</button>
<button onclick="showElem()">Show TEST</button>

<div class="settings-menu">
  <div id="test">TEST</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll test it on my side and will leave a comment later on, thanks for this ^_^

Comment: this may not help on my actual code but thanks for helping me understand its difference ^_^